# Leaflet angular error not render properly

Tags: angularjs, angular-leaflet-directive

I am trying to implement a simple leaflet map in my angular test page. I am having the problem you see in the photo attached.

[image]

My code is the code in this example:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/tombatossals/4PhzC/
```

I have some other things in my page as for example bootstrap libraries to draw some lists and jquery lib. Also, I import ngroutes and socket components . And I am painting the map webpage inside this directive:

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

I don't know why inthe example it works and in mine, it doesn't render fine.

Comment: demo works fine, please provide demo that replicates problem

Comment: https://nodetestuc.herokuapp.com/angular#/mapa this is where I am testing the app. Try just the map part, the socket part works fine if server sends a message